# Random folders being created on assets directory Yii

Tags: yii

Can someone explain me why random folders are being created at assets directory of my Yii project. Since I am using SVN to control the versions, is it necessary to commit those folders as well ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those folders are the js, css, and image files needed for various widgets and other parts of the Yii framework. You do NOT want to commit them to a repository, as Yii automatically regenerates a fresh copy if they don't exist.

Just create the folder for it, wipe out the contents of the folder if you upgrade to new versions of widgets, and don't add them to your repo.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/148/understanding-assets/